asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError when using Dask LocalCluster with processes=False and progress
This is an example:
import numpy as np
import zarr
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
from dask import array as da
from dask.distributed import progress

def same(x):
    return x

x = np.arange(100000)

with LocalCluster(processes=False, n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=2) as cluster, Client(cluster) as client:
    da_x = da.from_array(x,chunks=(2000,))
    da_y = da_x.map_blocks(same)
    futures = client.persist(da_y)
    progress(futures,notebook=False)
    y = da.compute(futures)[0]

And it will produce:
[########################################] | 100% Completed |  0.3s
2024-04-15 18:37:18,521 - distributed.core - ERROR - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/kangl/miniforge3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 803, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/kangl/miniforge3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 7203, in feed
    await asyncio.sleep(interval)
  File "/users/kangl/miniforge3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 605, in sleep
    return await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

But when I change to cluster to LocalCluster(processes=True, n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=2). It just works without any problem.
I am using
dask                      2023.9.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2023.9.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

I find a similar question at https://dask.discourse.group/t/error-in-monitoring-progress-of-distributed-work-related-to-asyncio/2559 but no solution yet. I don't know if they are related.
